# Is there any way to show all GitHub tickets without an assignee?

Tags: github

It seems kinda silly that this feature wouldn't be there.  I feel like I am overlooking something obvious, but I haven't been able to Google any answer successfully.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@LyndenShields's answer doesn't seem to work anymore.

At this date (March 16, 2015), the way to search for issues that have no assignee is to use the `no:` qualifier in the issues Filter field:

```
no:assignee
```

[image: new github issue filter no assignee]

Alternatively, you could use the following query string to achieve the same:

```
https://github.com/<username>/<repo>/issues?q=no%3Aassignee
```

<s>**EDIT**: Note that I could not make it work if I only had one qualifier specified (ie. you may need to add another one and have it like `no:assignee is:open`).</s>

**EDIT #2** (March 16, 2016): the above edit is not accurate anymore (hence the strikethrough); GitHub now accepts search queries with one qualifier only.

**EDIT #3** (July 26, 2017): removed the `%01` from the end of the URL - it basically is an unused character, but I believe GitHub interpreted it as a space. Indeed, when you use it this way, GitHub will automatically add a space, I guess to make sure other qualifiers can easily be added. Strangely, though, it will add a `%20` to the end of the URL today, but again, you can simply omit that part. The `%3A` between the words `no` and `assignee` is the character code for `Colon`. See a full list [here](https://www.obkb.com/dcljr/charstxt.html).

**EDIT #4** (June 30, 2020): this is now possible via the UI: simply go to your issues list (`https://github.com/<username>/<repo>/issues`) then choose `Assigned to nobody` from the Assignee dropdown:

[image: Assigned to nobody selected in the Assignee dropdown on the issues list of a GitHub repository]

Answer (score 10):

Go to the issues list and show issues assigned to yourself. Look in the URL bar and change where it has your username to `none` just after 'assigned/' and press enter. The UI will look the same but the list will have only unassigned issues.

e.g.:

```
https://github.com/<username>/<repo>/issues/assigned/none
```

Comment: As it stands (June 30, 2020) this would return a 404 Page not found error page.

Answer (score 4):

One workaround would be to compare:

- the list of issues
- with the list of issue assigned to anyone

(the difference being the list of issues not yet assigned)

See [GitHub V3 Api "list-issues-for-a-repository"](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository) section:

```
assignee
```

> String User login
>
> - `none`: for Issues with no assigned User.
> - `*`: for Issues with any assigned User.

Answer (score 0):

2021 Update.
In the search bar you must type `no:assignee` and this will show all Github issues without an individual assigned to it.